# How to generate a random network but keep the original node degree using networkx?

Tags: python, networking, networkx

I have a network, and how to generate a random network but ensure each node retains the same degre of the original network using networkx? My first thought is to get the adjacency matrix, and perform a random in each row of the matrix, but this way is somwhat complex, e.g. need to avoid self-conneted (which is not seen in the original network) and re-label the nodes. Thanks!

Comment: @closevoters: given that networkx has a function that does almost exactly this (`configuration_model`), I don't think this is too broad of a question.

Comment: Thank you! I should have read the whole docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [`expected_degree_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.expected_degree_graph.html). It generates a random graph based on a sequence of expected degrees, where each degree in the list corresponds to a node. It also even includes an option to disallow self-loops!

You can get a list of degrees using [`networkx.degree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.degree.html). Here's an example of how you would use them together in networkx 2.0+ (`degree` is slightly different in 1.0):

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.generators.degree_seq import expected_degree_graph

N,P = 3, 0.5
G = nx.generators.random_graphs.gnp_random_graph(N, P)
G2 = expected_degree_graph([deg for (_, deg) in G.degree()], selfloops=False)
```

Note that you're *not* guaranteed to have the exact degrees for each node using `expected_degree_graph`; as the name implies, it's probabilistic given the *expected value* for each of the degrees. If you want something a little more concrete you can use [`configuration_model`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model.html), however it does not protect against parallel edges or self-loops, so you'd need to prune those out and replace the edges yourself.

Comment: I would recommend `configuration_model`.  In the limit of large `N`, there are still some parallel edges or self-loops, but their "density" in the graph is low, meaning they don't really influence any dynamic process one might have in the graph.  I think this is often better than settling for a graph where the degree distribution is different.

Comment: @jtimmons I found an old thread talking about [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/networkx-discuss/_I7OGIsc2wk) and [double_edge_swap](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.swap.double_edge_swap.html) was recommended. I'm new to this. Can I use this to permute the network? Thanks!